# Cannot sign into gmail, all other websites are opening

Tags: firefox, gmail

The following error shows every time I sign into Gmail. On the contrary, I can open Gmail in Windows.

> The connection has timed out 
>   The server at www.google.com is taking too long to respond.
>
> 1. The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
> 2. If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
> 3. If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Please help.

Comment: @dhanam: Could you please give some details about your internet connection - wired/wireless, direct/requires password, static/dynamic ip, etc?

Comment: Maybe google is banned in your country (China)?

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and type: 
`ping google.com`

You should get something like this.

```
64 bytes from iy-in-f105.1e100.net (209.85.225.105): icmp_req=3 ttl=50 time=34.0 ms`
```

Do a control C to stop the continuous output
If just sits their with no output

- your not hooked to the internet
- or Name resolution is not working.

To check the name resolution part ping google's IP address: `ping 209.85.225.105`

Expected output:

```
PING 209.85.225.105 (209.85.225.105) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 209.85.225.105: icmp_req=1 ttl=50 time=35.1 ms
```

Do a control C to stop the continuous output.

- If it did not work in first step and this does work--DNS problem report back
- If it did not work in ether your Linux software is NOT hooked up to the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue, even after updating the proxy address.
But here is what I did and it started working for me.

1. Open Mozilla Firefox
2. Click Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Network -> Settings
3. Check "Use this proxy server for all protocols"

I already had a proxy address and port, but I did not click on "use this proxy server for all protocols". When I click it and closed the browser, Gmail started working.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox should work well with Gmail from any operating system, however it could be a glitch of Firefox (its configuration) or a faulty firefox plugin.

Try to login to Gmail by mean of Google Chrome (Chromium) or Opera browsers, then check what type of connection you are using (http or https). Google strongly suggest to use an HTTPS. Try to switch to 'http and https' connection settings. I think Firefox should open Gmail by HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, test if the problem occurs with other browsers.

**If the problem occurs with other browsers:**

Is possibly a network issue, like DNS resolution. In this case disable ipv6 in grub.

```
gksudo gedit  /etc/default/grub
```

Then replace the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”
```

With the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”ipv6.disable=1 quiet splash”
```

Then update grub and reboot:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If that doesn't help, try a different DNS server like [OpenDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDNS) or [Google Public DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/).

**If the problem occurs only with Firefox:**

Clear your browser cookies and browser cache, then try again. If that doesn't help, disable ipv6 in Firefox preferences.

1. Type **about:config** in the address bar, press Enter.
2. Find **network.dns.disableIPv6** in the list.
3. Right-click -> Toggle.
4. Restart Firefox and try again.

If that doesn't help, start Firefox in safe mode. Close Firefox, then:

```
firefox -safe-mode
```

If that works, then is an extension affecting your login. You can disable all extensions from the safe mode starting dialog and then enable one-by-one until you find the culprit.

If that doesn't help, create a new Firefox profile and test it. You can create a new profile by starting the profile manager. Close Firefox, then:

```
firefox -P
```

If that solves the problem, then see the tutorial "[Fixing a problematic or corrupted profile](http://firefox-tutorials.blogspot.com/2010/05/fixing-problematic-or-corrupted-profile.html)". If the problem persist even when using a new profile, then create a new Ubuntu user and test it. You can do that from "System >> Administration >> Users and Groups". If the problem does not persist when using a new user account, then you need to figure out which of your Gnome settings is affecting the Gmail login. Report back with the results.

Comment: Maybe it was a fluke but the grub fix messed up my Linux kernel. Kernel panic on boot. I had to boot from a different kernel (via the boot screen "Advanced options for Ubuntu" menu), undo the change to the grub config, and then from recovery mode do "package repair."

Answer (score 0):

The problem may also be related to your cookies. This could happen if you have an invalid cookie. Try removing all google/gmail cookies and then try to load the site - http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Deleting+cookies